# Nuxt bridge - Showing a loading indicator between pages

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-bridge

I recently migrated a Nuxt 2 Project to Nuxt Bridge, and everything is working fine, **except**... the loading bar is not showing up between pages. The `loading` property in `nuxt.config.js` is only for Nuxt 2, and I can't integrate the `<NuxtLoadingIndicator/>` of Nuxt 3. I also tried to create a custom component that would react to hooks such as `page:start`, but I can't make them be called.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the code below:

```js
const get = async ({page = 1}) => {
  const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()
  nuxtApp.callHook('page:start')
  tokens.value = await $api.index<models.TokenResults>('/token', { page: page })
  nuxtApp.callHook('page:finish')
}
```

You can see the details in the [link](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/15232)